# How can we rewrite a query with a subquery in SELECT clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How would you rewrite the following query into one without subquery as much as possible?

```
Select dept name,
                 (Select Count(*)
                    From instructor
                   Where department.dept name = instructor.dept name
                 ) As num_instructors
 From department;
```

I  came up with the following. Is it a good equivalence to the above?

```
   Select dept name, count(*)
     From department, instructor
    Where department.dept name = instructor.dept name
 Group By department.dept_name;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could write using left join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to write the query uses explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
select d.dept_name, count(i.dept_name)
from department d left join
     instructor i
     on d.dept_name = i.dept_name
group by d.dept_name;
```

If you only care about departments that have at least one instructor, then no `join` is necessary at all:

```
select i.dept_name, count(*)
from instructor i
group by i.dept_name;
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain what is not proper about my solution?

Comment: @Ben Your solution uses implicit join syntax (commas between tables in the `FROM` clause).  Explicit join syntax (explicitly stating each `JOIN`) is the proper way to write it.

Comment: @AaronDietz Thanks.  If it is just cross product, shall I use `JOIN` instead of comma? For example, `SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2` instead of `SELECT * FROM table1, table2`?

Comment: @Ben That would be a `CROSS JOIN` so `SELECT * FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2`.  Same results, just the preferred syntax as the comma version is depreciated.  The wiki does a good job with explaining each and usually showing both explicit/implicit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: Thanks. Where does it say " the comma version is depreciated"? @AaronDietz

Comment: @Ben I believe ANSI-92 (1992) introduced explicit joins and is usually the date cited as the depreciation of implicit comma joins.  There is some argument about the true depreciation date but you definitely want to use explicit joins if for no other reason than clarity. Here is a good quick read: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: @Ben . . . I don't believe that commas are deprecated.  I think that's because they don't take a popular vote on the subject (i.e. there is too much old code that the standards committee does not want to invalidate).

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is really close, just a couple things..

You should use explicit joins (ie. `JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN` etc.) instead of implicit joins (commas in the `FROM` clause). Implicit joins are 25+ years depreciated.

Also, in this case you will want a `LEFT JOIN` or no departments will be displayed that don't have instructors.  `LEFT JOIN` will retain departments without instructors and give you a 0 count (like the first query), where a `JOIN` would not display those at all.

```
SELECT d.dept_name, COUNT(i.dept_name) as num_instructors
FROM department d
LEFT JOIN instructors i on d.dept_name = i.dept_name
GROUP BY d.dept_name
```

Comment: You want `count(i.dept_name)` not `count(*)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Why "not count(*)"?

Comment: @Ben `COUNT(*)` counts rows, so it would return a minimum of 1 for every department.  `COUNT(i.dept_name)` would return a 0 if there was no instructor in that department.

Comment: Do you mean `COUNT` doesn't count `NULL`?  department is on the left hand side of LEFT JOIN, so i.dept_name is never NULL, and `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(i.dept_name)` are the same, correct?

Comment: But `instructors` is on the "right hand side" so `i.dept_name` can absolutely be null. `i.dept_name` is the value of `dept_name` from the `instructors`  table. `d.dept_name` is the value of `dept_name` from the `departments` table. And yes, all aggregate functions  ignore NULL values

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If all aggreation functions ignore NULL values, why does `COUNT(*) ` not?

Comment: Because `*` is never null